# How to transfer custom object between two WPF windows

Tags: wpf

I am a newbie to WPF and any suggestion will be appreciated.

I have a WPF app. As the user click the "NEXT" button of the mainWindow, it will connect to a remote database. If db connection succeed, the second window will show up and read more information from the database and show some stuff. I use a class SQLRead to do the database connection job.

```
public class SQLRead
{
    public string sql;
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    public int counter, length, dIndex, cdIndex, sdIndex;
    public int[,] data;
    public char[,] cdata;
    public string[,] sdata;

    public SQLRead()
    {
        sql = ""; counter = 0; length = 0;
        dIndex = 0; cdIndex = 0; sdIndex = 0;
    }

    public void NewConnection()
    {
        //if (conn != null) conn.Close();
        conn = new SqlConnection(
            @"Data Source = TheServer\TheInstance
              Integrated Security = SSPI;");
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        conn.Open();
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
```

My question is how to transfer the SQLRead instance to the second window?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you pass it to the constructor for the second window?

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an application scoped shared variable to hole the Sqlread object? Then you can access it from anywhere in the app:

```
class Application
{
    internal static SQLRead sharedSQLRead { get; set; }
}
```

In MainWindow:

```
Application.sharedSQLRead = new SQLRead();
```

In second window:

```
Application.sharedSQLRead.doWhatever();
```

It seems easier than passing around a reference....